# How to access IBM Watson Tone Analyzer via Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, tone-analyzer

I am able to run the following from the terminal

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary @{path_to_file}tone.json \
"{url}/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21&sentences=false" \
```

but not sure how to make it work within Laravel. Looking for some sample code. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, sorry but this is not a coding service and your question is a bit broad. You will find difficult to get an answer if you don't have some specific programming problem. Please show us what you have you tried so far.

Comment: I agree with dparoli. However in order to do this in Laravel you need to have a controller, such as IBMWatsonController that will contain your methods, such as (for example) analyzeTone(). There are different structures of controllers and methods, but that's a simple way to do it. It's going to take some playing around with it probably, in order to get it working. I usually like to dd() variables so I can see what's happening. I'm sure you'll get it working!

Comment: I have already added the code for fetching it from the server

Comment: Controller:
 // sending the data to the view
`return view('home', compact('response'));`

View:
//Data displayed in my view
`{"document_tone":{"tones":[{"score":0.730601,"tone_id":"sadness","tone_name":"Sadness"},{"score":0.70123,"tone_id":"tentative","tone_name":"Tentative"}]}}`

Now what I want is to loop through in a way where i can get all the tone_name and scores

Comment: @Scott Please edit your original question and add the code there.